# Proving something is a Banach Space

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Prove that $(\ell ^∞,||·||_∞)$ is a Banach space using the following steps.

Let $(x_n)_{n∈\mathbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(\ell ^∞,||·||_∞)$. For $n > 1$, let $x_n = (a_{1,n},a_{2,n},...,a_{k,n},...)$.

(a) Prove that for every ﬁxed $k \geq 1$, the sequence of real numbers $(a_{k,n})_{n>1}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$. Therefore conclude that $(a_{k,n})_{n>1}$ converges to a limit $y_k ∈ \mathbb R$.

Steps (b), (c), (d), I didn't write yet.

Let $\varepsilon /2 >0$. Then $\exists N $ such that $n,m > N$, we have:

$$|| a_{k,n} - a_{k,m}||_{\infty} = \sup _{k \geq 1} | a_{k,n} - a_{k,m}| \leq\sup _{k \geq 1} | a_{k,n} |+\sup _{k \geq 1} | - a_{k,m}| = \sup _{k \geq 1} | a_{k,n} |+\sup _{k \geq 1} | a_{k,m}|  $$

I kind of guessed all of this so far so it might be wrong... I don't really know what to do. Please help.

Comment: Are b), c),d) given as steps in your excercise?

Comment: @Roland yeah I just didn't bother to write them down because I cant even do the step (a)

Answer (score 0):

For $y\in \ell^\infty$ , $y= (y_1,y_2,\dots)$, and $k\in \mathbb N$ we have that $$|y_k|\leq \sup_{k \in \mathbb N}|y_k|= \| y\|_\infty.$$

If $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} = (a_{1,n}, a_{2,n}, \dots)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then we have by definition that for every $\epsilon > 0$  there exists some $N \in \mathbb N$ such that we can conclude from $n,m > N$ that $\|x_n -x_m\|< \epsilon$.

Let $k\in \mathbb N$. For $\epsilon > 0$, we choose $N$ like above and insert $y = x_n - x_m$ in the equation. We get that for $n,m > N$ $|a_{k,n} - a_{k,m}|<\epsilon$. This means that the sequence $(a_{k,1}, a_{k,2}, \dots$ (not that $k$ is fixed) is a real sequence which is Chauchy as well, i.e. it converges to some $a_{k}\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Every Cauchy sequence of real numbers converge.

Comment: Since (x_n) is a Cauchy sequence in real numbers (it doesn't say its in real numbers though so unsure on this), then $\exists N_1 $ s.t. $||x_n||<\varepsilon /2$ and $\exists N_2 $ s.t. $||x_m||<\varepsilon /2$ So $$|y_k|\leq \sup_{k \in \mathbb N}|y_k|= \| y\|_\infty = \sup_{k \in \mathbb N}|x_n| + \sup_{k \in \mathbb N}|x_m| < \varepsilon /2 + \varepsilon /2$$ But this is for these x sequences, not for $(a_{k,n})$.........

Comment: Is $x_n = (a_{k,n})_{k \in \mathbb N}$?

Comment: @snowman: I'd assume that $\ell^\infty$ denotes real-valued bounded sequences here. Yes, $x_n = (a_{1,n}, a_{2,n}, \dots) =  (a_{k,n})_{k \in \mathbb N}$. This is _not_ the definition of Cauchy sequences what you're using.

Comment: @snowman: I've expanded the answer to repeat the definition of Cauchy sequences and provided more detail and explicity.

Comment: where did M come from?

Comment: @snowman A typo. It's the $N$ you get from $x_n$ being Cauchy.

Comment: why is it n,m<N? I would have thought it is >

Comment: I dont understand why you wrote the first bit. Can I just say the following: Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, then $\forall \varepsilon >0, \, \, \exists N \in \mathbb N $ s.t. for $n,m >N$, we have $$||x_n - x_m||_{\infty} < \varepsilon$$ So since $$x_n = (a_{1,n},a_{2,n},...,a_{k,n},...)=(a_{k,n})_{k \geq 1}$$ and $$x_m = (a_{1,n},a_{2,n},...,a_{k,m},...)=(a_{k,m})_{k \geq 1}$$ then $$||a_{k,n} - a_{k,m}||_{\infty} < \varepsilon$$ so $(a_{k,n})_{k \geq 1}$ is Cauchy ????

Comment: This is just for the first part of the question. I wanna deal with the next part after...

Comment: please help....